# What effect does having 'measured' as a parameter in additive white gaussian noise?

Tags: matlab, modulation, bit-rate, awg, bit-error

I'm comparing the bit error rate of various modulation schemes with additive white gaussian noise in MATLAB.

There's the option to have this noise using 'measured' which measures the power of a signal before adding noise to it. When using this, the signal ossicilates a lot more, but I don't understand why/how this is.

If it's just measuring the power, why would this affect the BER performance?

[Link to the MATLAB documentation.](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/awgn.html)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the page you linked:

> out = awgn(in,snr) adds white Gaussian noise to the vector signal in. **This syntax assumes that the power of in is 0 dBW**.
>
> out = awgn(in,snr,signalpower) accepts an input signal power value in dBW. **To have the function measure the power of in before adding noise, specify signalpower as 'measured'.**

So if you don't provide this parameter, Matlab will assume the input signal power is 0 dBW, and scale the added noise to give the requested SNR relative to 0 dBW.

If you provide a numerical value for the `signalpower`, Matlab will assume that power instead of 0 dBW.

if you specify 'measured', Matlab will measure the power of the input signal and scale the added noise relative to its actual power rather than to 0 dBW or some other specified level.

Comment: Ah, rather silly of me, thank you very much!